# Can we say "do a class"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage

Do you think, "do a class" is a plausible phrase? For example, let's say a teacher is going to give a class at 2:30, can he/she say, "I will do a class at 2:30"? Or if he/she is giving a class at the moment, can  she say to someone, say, on the phone, "I am doing a class"?

I also wonder if a student can also say that he/she is doing a class when he is given the class. What do you think?

Comment: I suspect students are more likely to say do a class than staff.

Comment: I suspect both pupils *and* teachers are more likely to ***take*** a class. But the OP here is obviously happy to have the teacher ***give*** a class, and I can't see any advantage in switching from ***give*** to ***do*** in this context.

Comment: It could be -- what's the context here?

Comment: @FeliniusRex Let's say I am a teacher and I am giving a class. I forgot to turn my phone off and someone called me during the class. Can I say something like, "I am doing a class right now. I will call you later"?

Comment: @FireandIce For informal, spoken language, maybe. Because of the certifications required and all the hoops teachers have to jump through, they'd still likely say something not as slangy, like, "I'm in class right now -- call you later" or "Teaching right now -- call you later." In America at least, teachers are still not quite as informal as their students.

Answer (score 1):

"Do" a class is very awkward and does not sound like how a native speaker would express this.

A teacher would say about the future:

- "I'm teaching a class at 2:30"
- "I have a class at 2:30"
- "I'll be teaching a class at 2:30"
- "I'll be in class at 2:30"

For present:

- "I'm teaching a class right now"
- "I'm in class right now"